# Error: No cached version of 'x' available for offline mode

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, offline-caching, offline-mode

I used Android Studio 1.5 and gradle build successfully. But after upgrading AS to version 2.0.0.20 I get this error:

> Error:No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2 available for offline mode.

Other answers on Stack Overflow suggest going online but however the computer does not have Internet access.

What can I do? Can I copy the previous downloaded library? where is the cache path? Where should I copy the cached files?